# Add text before selected text in another textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, text, richtextbox

I'm having issues with trying to get one textbox to change another.

Explanation:
There are two richTextBoxes (rich1, rich2).
rich1 and rich2 will have a string in there that was chosen by the user (their server name). There are buttons on the form that change the selected text in rich1 to different colours using this:

```
private void btnDarkBlue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rich1.SelectionColor = Color.DarkBlue;
    }
```

What I'd like to happen is when somebody clicks a colour button, the selected text in rich1 is the same in rich2 but I want to add text before the selected text in rich2, for example if somebody selects "nh" out of "Funhaus" then rich2 would equal "Fu\colour=12\nhaus"

So in the end, rich1 would display (with colouring): "Funhaus". But rich2 would display (with no colouring): "Fun\colour=12haus" as the user has decided to change the word "haus" to DarkBlue. Here's some code I've tried:

```
rich2.SelectedRtf = rich1.SelectedRtf;
```

I assumed that because they both equal the same text this would work, however this just seems to add rich1's selected text to the beginning of rich2 with formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 private void rich1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rich2.SelectionLength = rich1.SelectionLength;
        rich2.SelectionStart = rich1.SelectionStart;

    }

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rich2.SelectedRtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi{colour=12}" + rich2.SelectedRtf;
        rich1.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert formatted text into a `RichTextBox` control without changing its other formattings, then use the SelectedText property, and only apply the format afterwards:

```
private void btnDarkBlue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rich1.SelectionColor = Color.DarkBlue;
    rich2.SelectionStart = rich1.SelectionStart;
    rich2.SelectionLength = 0;
    rich2.SelectedText = whateverTextYouLike;
    rich2.SelectionColor = Color.DarkBlue; //<-- apply any format if you like only after setting selected text
}
```

This should work if both `rich1` and `rich2` have exactly the same string when you press the button.